# 2-phase commit of POX/Rest endpoint + database insert

Tags: transactions, wso2, jta, wso2-esb

I'm trying to create a transactional unit which sends a RESTful HTTP post and inserts this data into a table.

Although I have an onError handler for the local sequence, When I disable connectivity to my endpoint, rather than failing the 'send' mediator puts the endpoint in a SUSPENDED state.  It then continues to skip the send and only insert the data.  Further, my custom failureSequence complains that I'm not in a transaction, even though it is invoked 'after' I've called `<transaction action="new"/>`

While I have read the docs and understand that going into SUSPEND is the default behaviour for a failing Endpoint, I actually want more control.  I would like to trigger my own sequence on failure (or receipt of some specific HTTP response code) and call a `<transaction action="rollback"/>`

For clarity, the relevant part of my sequence looks as follows:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="csvToDatabaseRollback">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="text" value="Rolling back transaction"/>
   </log>
   <transaction action="rollback"/>
   <!-- rollback any other state, here -->
</sequence>

<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="csvRow2Pc" onError="csvToDatabaseRollback">
   <transaction action="new"/>
   <log level="full">
      <property name="State" value="Iteration"/>
   </log>
   <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="text" value="Calling rest-endpoint"/>
   </log>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:80/spotify" format="pox"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="text" value="After HTTP POST"/>
   </log>
   <dbreport useTransaction="true">
      <connection>
        ....
      </connection>
      <statement>
         <sql>
            <![CDATA[   insert into file values (?, ?, ?)]]></sql>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            <parameter xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:sec="http://secservice.samples.esb.wso2.org" expression="//line/col_one/text()" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <parameter xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:sec="http://secservice.samples.esb.wso2.org" expression="//line/col_two/text()" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <parameter xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:sec="http://secservice.samples.esb.wso2.org" expression="//line/col_three/text()" type="VARCHAR"/>
         </statement>
      </dbreport>
      <log level="custom">
         <property name="text" value="Before tx commit"/>
      </log>
      <transaction action="commit"/>
</sequence>
```

The logs contain:

```
[2013-10-25 15:09:40,117]  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for :   localhost/127.0.0.1:80
[2013-10-25 15:09:40,116]  INFO - LogMediator text = After HTTP POST
[2013-10-25 15:09:40,129]  INFO - LogMediator text = Rolling back transaction
[2013-10-25 15:09:40,129]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint :   endpoint_f2e0b5550f82db317194145cb24b59f38a63ab610d8a994c - last suspend duration was :   30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Fri Oct 25 15:10:10 NZDT 2013
[2013-10-25 15:09:40,121]  INFO - LogMediator text = Before tx commit
[2013-10-25 15:09:40,131]  INFO - LogMediator text = Rolling back transaction
[2013-10-25 15:09:40,131] ERROR - TransactionMediator Unable to rollback transaction
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This method needs a transaction for the calling thread    and none exists.
Possible causes: either you didn't start a transaction,
it rolledback due to timeout, or it was committed already.
ACTIONS: You can try one of the following: 
1. Make sure you started a transaction for the thread.
```

If I check the database the rows have been committed. Subsequent attempts will happily just skip the 'send' mediator, as it is suspended.

Ideally I'd like to send the HTTP POST and have custom routing rules based on the REST response, rather than a suspend.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When the endpoint is suspended esb will call faultsequence. Within the faultsequence you can call any of your sequence. Therefore it gives you the control to put your custom code.

Comment: Thanks.  I've demonstrated that above.  The problem isn't that my faultsequence isn't getting called; it is that: i) When I rollback within the fault sequence, it doesn't recognise the outer transaction; see the error above.  ii) the Endpoint gets suspended and is silently ignored on the next invocation.